# pymongo - ensureIndex and upserts

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a simple dict that defines a base record as shown below:

```
record = {
    'h': site_hash, #combination of date (below) and site id hashed with md5
    'dt': d,                            # date - YYYYMMDD
    'si': data['site'],                 # site id
    'cl': data['client'],               # client id
    'nt': data['type'],                 # site type
}
```

Then I call the following to update the record if it doesn't exist with the following:

```
collection.update(
    record, 
    {'$inc':updates}, # updates contain some values that increase such as events: 1, actions:1, etc
    True # do upsert
);
```

I was wondering if I change the above to the following if it would have better performance since the code below only looks existing 'h' values instead of h/dt/si/cl/nt and I'd only need ensureIndex on the 'h' field. However, obviously $set would execute every time causing more writes the record as opposed to just $inc.

```
record = {
    'h': site_hash, #combination of date (below) and site id hashed with md5
}
values = {
    'dt': d,                            # date - YYYYMMDD
    'si': data['site'],                 # site id
    'cl': data['client'],               # client id
    'nt': data['type'],                 # site type
}
collection.update(
    record, 
    {'$inc':updates,'$set':values},
    True # do upsert
);
```

Does anyone have any tips or suggestions on best practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'h' is already unique then you can just create an index on h, there's no need to index 'dt', 'si', etc. In that case I expect your first example to be a little more performant under very heavy load, for the somewhat obscure reason that it will create smaller entries in the journal.

Comment: When doing an upsert does mongo only search on indexed values to see if the record exists? So if I have a "unique index" created on "h", it will completely ignore the "dt", "si", etc fields when searching for the record (even if I have an key index on any of those fields?

Comment: No, MongoDB needs to compare the whole document, but it can look it up using the index and then compare the remainder of the fields, which is very fast.